# Imported module goes out of scope (unbound local error)

Tags: python, scope

I am getting a strange "unbound local" error in a python package that seems to defy all logic. I can't get a MWE to reproduce it, but will try to explain succinctly and hope that someone might be able to offer some explanation of what is going on.

For the sake of this example `module` is a package I developed, and `Model` is a class within `module`. The definition of the `Model` class (model.py) looks like:

```
import module

class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        print module

    def run(self):
        print module
```

Now, when I instantiate a `Model` in a script like this:

```
from model import Model
m = Model()
m.run()
```

`module` prints successfully within the `__init__`, but I get an unbound local error within the `run` function.

I attempted to diagnose this with pdb, which is where things got really weird, because if I add a pdb trace immediately prior to the `print module` line in the `run()` function, then I can successfully run `print module` without an unbound local error, but if I step to the next line then it throws the error. How can `module` be in the scope of `__init__()`, and in the scope of pdb, but not in the scope of `run()`?

I know this is not ideal since there is no MWE, but I cannot seem to reproduce this outside the context of the full code. I am hoping that someone will have an idea of what might possibly be going on and suggest some strategies to debug further.

Comment: Can you give us the full stack trace? That would be helpful in diagnosing to make sure it's an unbound local where you think it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you have a local variable named `module` somewhere in the function `run`. For example, the following code will throw `UnboundLocalError`

```
import sys

def run():
     print sys
     sys = None
run()
```

Here `sys = None` introduces a local name that shadows the imported `sys` inside `run` and at the time `print` invoked it is not yet defined, hence the error. To use the imported module inside `run` you have to find and rename the local variable.
More info on python scoping rules is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html)

Comment: This wasn't exactly it, but it did lead me to the answer. There was an "import module.function" call within the run() block (don't ask) that seemed to be the root of the problem. Easy fix once I found it... thanks!